# Can solana-web3.js or spl-token push new transactions to me?

Tags: spl-token, web3.js

I have an app that shows a user's previous transactions. Right now, after a new transaction is made in the app, when signature is confirmed, I'll run:

```
const rawTransaction = await connection.getParsedTransaction(signature, {});
```

And add this to the list of list of previous transactions.

Likewise, if a transaction is made for another app, I'll need to run `connection.getSignaturesForAddress()` and `connection.getParsedTransactions()` to pull the latest transactions in my app.

But is there a better way? Specifically **can I receive a message telling me about the new transaction (rather than polling for the transaction)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [subscribe to program logs](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#logssubscribe) that mention the user's pubkey.

Using [`@solana/web3.js`](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/tree/master/web3.js), you might do this:

```
const subscriptionId = connection.onLogs(
  walletAddress,
  ({signature}) => {
    console.log(signature);
  },
);
```

See the [onLogs() documentation](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#onLogs) for more options.